# Why is this a useState variable undefined within a const when it has already been set within a useEffect callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access a variable created by useState, but it is undefined when I try to access it. I can access it when I call the function with useClick, but not when I put it within useEffect.

```
function Viewer(props) {
    
    const [lines, setLines] = useState()
    const [linesToDisplay, setLinesToDisplay] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {

        if (props.json != undefined) {
            let l = props.json.lines.map((item => <Line json={item} />))
            setLines(l) // Lines are set.
            setLinesToDisplay(
                renderLinesAsColumns // Next, call renderLinesAsColumns.
            )
        }
       
    }, []
    )

    const renderLinesAsColumns = () => {

        var result = []

        lines.forEach(line => { // ERROR: "lines is undefined". But lines was already set!
            result.push(line) 
        })

        setLinesToDisplay(result) // set lines to display
    }


}
```

Why does this happen? I can confirm that `lines` has been set before `renderLinesAsColumns` is ever called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The misunderstanding is that when you call

```
setLines(l) // Lines are set.
```

it is actually

```
setLines(l) // Lines will be set, the next time we render.
```

But since you call `renderLinesAsColumns` before the next render, when you call it, `lines` is still undefined.  And then when it renders again, it will never call `renderAsLinesAsColumns` with the updated value.

You probably want to do:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.json != undefined) {
        let l = props.json.lines.map((item => <Line json={item} />))
        setLines(l) // Lines are set.
    }
}, [])
useEffect(() => {
    if (lines && lines.length) {
        setLinesToDisplay(
            renderLinesAsColumns // Next, call renderLinesAsColumns.
        );
    }
}, [lines])
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. I have one brief follow-up if you don't mind answering. Is it normal to have a ton of `useEffect`'s throughout a component? I could see this getting quite messy if we have a lot of setup to do.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't have so many useEffects - I typically only have them for for handling potential HTTP requests.  In this case you could avoid the second `useEffect` by just passing in lines to `renderLinesAsColumns` as an argument, rather than setting it on the state, or by doing some like `render() { /* ... */ renderLinesAsColumns(lines).map((line) => <div key={line.id}>{line.content}</div>) }`

Comment: That approach is cleaner. I've done that. Much appreciated.